# Why the sequence generated by $x+e^x$ is $(1,x,\frac{x^2}{2!},\frac{x^3}{3!},\frac{x^4}{4!}\ldots)$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am trying to find the sequence generated by $x+e^x$. I have the sequence generated by the function $e^x$ which is $\displaystyle (1,x,\frac{x^2}{2!},\frac{x^3}{3!},\frac{x^4}{4!},\ldots)$, as for the sequence generated by $x$, I've seen one example in the book in which it's possible to obtain it doing the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
{\frac{1}{1-x}}&=&{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots}\\
{}&&{}\\
{\left[ \frac{1}{1-x}\right]' }&=&{0+1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots}\\
{}&&{}\\
{ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} }&=&{0+1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots}\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now using: $f(x),g(x)$ generating functions of the sequences $(a_r),(b_r)$, we have:
$Af(x)+Bg(x)$ Is the generating function to the sequence $(Aa_r+Bb_r)$.

I believe that this indicates that I should sum term by term:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
{}&&{}\\
{ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+e^x }&=&{[0+1]+[1+x]+[2x+\frac{x^2}{2!}]+[3x^2+\frac{x^3}{3!}]+[4x^3+\frac{x^4}{4!}]+\ldots}\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

But it doesn't add up to the desired sequence. What did I do wrong?

Comment: $x$ is just $x$, why should it have anything to do with ${1\over 1-x}$ or this other stuff?

Comment: Isn't it needed to use $\frac{1}{1-x}$? There is a part in the book where they derive it via $\frac{1}{1-x}$, I also questioned myself why all that was needed, but perhaps it was to enforce that the generating function is on the form $\sum_k a_kn^k$.

Comment: It is not. $x$ is the generating function for the sequence $(0,1,0,0,0,\ldots, 0,\ldots)$. The function ${1\over 1-x}$ generates a totally different sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ itself is a power series

$$0+x+0x^2+0x^3+\dots$$,

so

$$x+e^x=1+2x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\dots.$$

Comment: I don't understand: Why $x$ generates the sequence $(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$? I was thinking that it would generate the sequence $(0,1,2,3,4,\ldots)$.

Comment: How is $x=x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots$? Any polynomial is its own power series.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. While $e^x$ is a series, $x$ is only a monomial. I thought it was a series too.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

The sequence generated by $e^x$ is
$$
(1,1,\frac{1}{2!},\frac{1}{3!},\frac{1}{4!},\ldots),
$$
and the sequence for $x$ is just
$$
(0,1,0,0,\ldots),
$$
and thus the sequence generated by the sum, $x+e^x$, is just the sum of the sequences,
$$
(1,2,\frac{1}{2!},\frac{1}{3!},\frac{1}{4!},\ldots).
$$

I assume that you mean by "the sequence generated by $f(x)$", the sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ such that we can expand $f(x)$ as 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i
$$

Comment: Why the sequence for $x$ is just $(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$?

Comment: @Vÿska I edited my answer in order to reflect under what I understand what you mean by "the sequence generated by". Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. My mistake was to think that $x$ was a series like $e^x$, it's only a monomial, I guess.